# Can't delete a file when it is an argument

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I'll put my code first:

```
@Post
public Representation post(InputStream zip) throws Throwable {
    createFile(zip, "C:/temp\abc.zip");
    return new StringRepresentation("File uploaded");
}    

public void createFile(InputStream zipStream, uploadedFileLocation) throws Exception {
    try {
        writeToFile(zipStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw e;
        }
}


private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        uploadedInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am trying make a server that allows a user to upload a zip file.  The server then write the zip file to disk, unzip it, then delete the zip while keeping the unzipped portion on the server.  However, when I send the zip file to my server, it cannot get deleted.  When using `FileUtils.forceDelete()`, it says that it cannot delete the file.  It is ideal for the zip to be deleted after it is unzipped.

EDIT:  I can only delete the file after `post(InputStream zip)` returns.  If I call delete from within the `post` method, it won't delete because post hasn't returned.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Hmm. It appears you're trying to delete a directory?</strike>

```
FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
```

But `uploadedFileLocation` is "C:\temp" from your `post` method. I'm not sure if this would cause the issue, or if this is intended behavior, but that code does not delete the zip file, and is attempting to delete the actual C:\temp directory.

Also, potentially worth noting: in your `writeToFile` method, you're initializing `OutputStream out` twice. I'm not 100% on this, but it could be that the first initialization is holding the file pointer open until the entire object is deleted from the stack (i.e., when `post` returns). Take out the second initialization and see if any changes occur?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentily omitted it.  There is infact a file name there now.  `C:/temp/abc.zip`

Comment: In that case, I'm still leaning towards the double-initialized output stream that potentially holds the file at that location open until the object is out of the stack.

I'm not familiar with the FileUtils library, but I do know that the `java.io.File` class does have its own delete function. Perhaps if the first method doesn't work, try `new File(fileUploadLocation).delete()`.

Also also, do you get an exception message when it fails? If so, can you add it to your post?

Comment: It turns out I should have called `file.delete();` instead of using `FileUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem might be caused by you using "C:/temp" instead of "C:/temp/fileName", so you end up trying to delete a folder, that you might not have permissions to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use file location, why not use the actual file?
Pass the file as an argument and do `file.delete();` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not that you are trying to delete a directory, then it is most likely that the file you are trying to delete is still open.  On Windows, that means that will stop you from deleting the file.

By the looks of it, your `writeToFile` method opens the file twice ... but only closes it once.  I suspect that that means that it will leak a file descriptor, and the OS will think that the application is still using the file.

---

> It turns out I should have called file.delete(); instead of using FileUtils.

I don't think so.  Sure, you won't get an exception due to the file not being deleted.  But instead `File.delete()` will return `false` and your application will leave the file in the file system.  In the long term, that could be worse, unless you've got something else in place to clean out the orphaned files.